# MongoDB return only matched sub-sub document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

[image]

Given the above document structure, in mongodb, how do you guys filter a specific terminal whose id matches the given parameter?

Comment: Can you provide a sample data set of your document structure?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your JSON looks like this, or similar:

```
{
    "Merchant_Account":"Merchant Name",
    "ID":"MA1",
    "Card_Acceptor":[{
        "ID":"CA1",
        "Vendor_ID":{
            "ID":"VID1"
        },
        "Terminal_ID":[
            "TID1",
            "TID2",
            "TID3"
        ]
    }]
}
```

You can retrieve this document using the following in Mongo Shell:

```
db.collection.find({"Card_Acceptor":{$elemMatch:{Terminal_ID:"TID1"}}})
```

This returns the whole document where a Terminal ID matches in the array of Terminal_IDs. The key here is the [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) array query operator.

Comment: That will return multiple terminals as well

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking or telling me, but the answer is yes, it will return multiple terminals as well. If there are multiple entries that have "TID1" as a Terminal_ID, they will all be returned. If you are expecting different results you're going to need to revise your question and be more specific. Adding sample data and the expected output would REALLY help get the correct answer for you.

Comment: If I pass TID1 as parameter value then, I would like the query to return

{
    "Merchant_Account":"Merchant Name",
    "ID":"MA1",
    "Card_Acceptor":[{
        "ID":"CA1",
        "Vendor_ID":{
            "ID":"VID1"
        },
        "Terminal_ID":[
            "TID1"
        ]
    }]
}